# Alternating left-right definition list

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a simple definition list in the following format:

```
    dl {
    margin: 0;
}

dl.interview dt {
    color: #A8A67A;
}

dl.interview dd {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.interview dt:before {
  content: 'Q. ';
}
.interview dd:before {
  content: 'A. ';
}

dt {
    margin-top: 1em
}

dd {
  font-style: italic;
    padding: 0;
}
```

how do I get each succeeding pair of questions and answers to alternate between left and right?

Comment: adding your html would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [nth-of-type](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-nth-of-type-selector/) selector. I adjusted the margin on your `dl.interview dt` and added a 0 margin to the top (dl, dl dt, dl dd).

Hope this helps

```css
dl, dl dt, dl dd {
  margin: 0;
}

dl.interview dt {
  color: #A8A67A;
}

dl.interview dd {
  /*margin-left: 0;*/
}

.interview dt:before {
  content: 'Q. ';
}

.interview dd:before {
  content: 'A. ';
}

dt {
  margin-top: 1em
}

dd {
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 0;
}

dd:nth-of-type(even){margin-left:65%;}
dt:nth-of-type(even){margin-left:65%;}
```

```html
<dl class="interview">
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
  <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
  <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Absolutely spot-on.  I changed it slightly to make it look better on smaller screens.

Comment: @DonaldJenkins Great! Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

hopefully I understood your question. 
In my Example, I added

```
dt, dd {
    margin-top: 1em;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

and removed

```
dd {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

as I guess, Q and A should start at the same height.

Have a look here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gJaqKW

It can also be solved with flex or grid. Just wanted to start easy ;)

I hope it helps.